# Compute the transition map of two charts.

Tags: analysis

Need to know how to compute the transition map of $h = g^{-1}\circ f$

The unit circle has charts $f(s) = (\cos(s),\sin(s))$ is element of $\Bbb R^2$,
for $-\pi < s < \pi$, and

$g(t) = \left(\cfrac{2t}{t^2 + 1}, \cfrac{t^2 - 1}{t^2 + 1}\right)$ for $t\in\Bbb R$.
Compute the transition map of $h = g^{-1}\circ f$

Sorry for my poor structure of the question.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck?  For example, can you compute $g^{-1}$?

Comment: That's exactly where I am stuck! I think i should be able to figure it out if i get g^-1

Comment: Well, set $x = \frac{2t}{t^2+1}$ and solve for $t$ using the quadratic formula.  In the quadratic formula, looking at the squareroot part (which ends up simplifying to $\pm\sqrt{1-x^2}$), notice that this is just another name for $y$.  In the end, I got $t = \frac{1+y}{x}$ as my answer.